# Can't fill a datatable with a statement that works in Ms Access but not through C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

The error I get when I try to `fill` a data table is:

```
The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.
```

The statement I use is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DatePart('M', Contracte.[Data]) as Month, DatePart('yyyy', Contracte.[Data]) as Year FROM Contracte;
```

If I try to execute it directly from Access it works but not from C#. `Data` is a `DateTime`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Month and Year are reserved words. Use []:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    DatePart('M', Contracte.[Data]) as [Month], 
    DatePart('yyyy', Contracte.[Data]) as [Year]
FROM Contracte;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DatePart('M', Contracte.[Data]) as 'Month', DatePart('yyyy', Contracte.[Data]) as 'Year' FROM Contracte;
```

this is because Month and Year are reserved keywords in SQL.